# what data type should i convert into since it always telling me error unhandled Exception of type 'system.FormatException' occured in mscorlib.dll

Tags: vb.net

1.i don't know what kind of data type suit the most or where is my fault neither

2.this is a POS program i tried to built about. POS for cafe or anykind of F&B services

```
Private Sub btnTotal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTotal.Click
        itemcost(0) = Convert.ToUInt32(txtClassic.Text) * 15000
        itemcost(1) = Convert.ToUInt32(txtGreentea.Text) * 15000
        itemcost(2) = Convert.ToUInt32(txtBlacksesame.Text) * 15000
        itemcost(3) = Convert.ToUInt32(txtPeppermint.Text) * 15000
```

4. the user input is the quantity of item.
   i expect the output is inputted qty * price(15000) in currency

Comment: So "it always telling me error" but you decided to not tell us what the error message was?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: FormatException was unhandled.
An unhandled Exception of type 'system.FormatException' occured in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Where is the declaration of itemcost

Comment: Dim itemcost(17) As UInt32
that is the declaration i used on top